# Importing database to Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle12c

I have installed oracle 12c and created my database(schema) on that. Now for the front end, I have installed oracle apex. Is there any way I can import my 12c database into the apex. I have searched and I found the way to import dataset but not a complete database. Is it possible? If yes, then please explain how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle APEX lives *in* the database. It's a feature. If you only have one instance, then everything is where it needs to be, you just need to start querying it.

Now there are security considerations, so your application's parsing schema needs access to whatever objects you want to utilise. This is standard Oracle security.

The only reason you need to mention 'front end' in your discussion is when you're talking about client-side behaviours that occur with Dynamic Actions.

Comment: so in order to access my database in apex, do I need to grant permission to apex on that database?

Comment: Stop thinking of APEX being different to the database. APEX is just an engine made of db components. This engine will use whatever user you specify to execute the commands to build each page. This user needs access to db tables/packages, just like any Oracle Forms user would. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/htmdb/managing-application-attributes.html#GUID-F2324900-0AD3-4C0A-8B86-AE4B9C25F991